# Arduino + Android : How to switch activity

Tags: android, android-activity, arduino, adk

I'm working on an Android application interacting with Arduino. I'm trying to manage multiple activities, each one being responsible for controlling a specific part of the Arduino board.

Unfortunately, tutorials on the web use only one activity. So I don't know how to proceed for keeping the connection with Arduino alive while navigating to a new Activity or for closing it properly and then re-open it on the new Activity.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to connect to Arduino and to keep that connection open. Your Activities can then talk to the Service, being started, stopped, switched, etc.

**EDIT**: How this can be done is already handled by another question/answer:

[Long running ADK Accessory (Service?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873261/long-running-adk-accessory-service)

Comment: +1 Great suggestion.  I'm doing a similar project and I may just use this method.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer. That sounds to be a good solution. But I don't really know how to process.

I'm using the DemoKit sample from Google (http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk.html) but it uses functions linked to the activity like getLastNonConfigurationInstance() in order to get the accessory. Those functions seem to not be available on a Service.

Also it uses a runnable to run the communication loop, should I use a runnable in my service too?

Do you have a sample code that I can use?

The code of the DemoKitActivity.java can be found here : http://bit.ly/OpNhgy

Comment: Looking at the linked source: the accessory is fetched initially from `UsbManager`. Beyond that: Sorry, I can't help you with ADK. You should explore the linked `Service` docs a little bit and _then_ formulate a _new_ question with the _specific_ problem. Handling this in the comments is frowned upon on this site. You might lookup the site FAQ for this.

Comment: @Ldoppea: FYI: I've found another answer for ADK+Services: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10052732/947357

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Arduino with Java before, but you might want to follow a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern. Using a Singleton pattern, whatever objects you are using to connect to it can be accessed from multiple activities and multiple threads.

Using a Singleton will only alleviate your problem though. You still need to figure out how to close/reopen it.

Also, it is important you know how the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) works. If a user receives a phone call, the screen turns off, or the orientation of the screen changes it will destroy your activity and recreate it. You'll have to handle how you're going to save and restore where you were. This will most likely mean you have to close/reopen the connection.

Comment: This is fragile. I've tried this approach, and got burned when Android unloaded the whole class in order to free some memory. Service approach described by @A.H. works like a clock.